# Moving element in a dictionary consisting of element:position pairs

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this: `{a:0, b:1, c:2}`. Field name and it's order in table, actually. I need to resort this structure so that (for example) if position of b becomes 0 then the result is `{b:0, a:1, c:2}`. If position of b becomes 2 then the result must be `{a:0, c:1, b:2}` and so on...

How this can be done? I can't use built-in functions (if any), because every field in that dictionary is  taken from more complex structure. I basically can only iterate over this dictionary, sorted or not, and change the position value.

I use Javascript/Coffeescript, but that doesn't matter - I would appreciate ideas in any language.

Comment: so if you have `k` entries then you'll only have values from `0` to `k-1`?

Comment: Yes. Preferably. Anyway I can sort the structure by index, then walk over it and apply i++ as a position so that 1,2,5 becomes 0,1,2 (for example). But if this can be done during the first (and only) iteration that would be better.

Comment: what is the order of magnitude for `k`? how often does the function need to be called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider what needs to happen: If you move some value from order n to order n', only the order of the values between order n and n' actually changes. If n > n', they move down by one, and if n < n' they move up by one. Here is some pseudocode:

```
function(dict, name, newOrder)
{
    var oldOrder = dict[name];
    foreach((k, order) in dict)
    {
        if(order > oldOrder && order <= newOrder)
            dict[k]--;
        else if(order >= newOrder && order < oldOrder)
            dict[k]++;
    }
    dict[name] = newOrder;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that doesn't iterate over all the elements in the map.
It's just complicated, I don't think it improves the speed much for small data sets.
sorry this is not proper javascript:

```
add = function(dict, vector, k)
{
    var size=len(vector);
    vector[size]=k;
    dict[k]=size;
}
swap(dict, vector, name, newOrder)
{   
    var oldOrder = dict[name]
    if(oldOrder < newOrder)
    {
        for(var i=oldOrder+1; i<=newOrder; i++)
        {  dict[vector[i]]--;
           vector[i-1]=vector[i];
        }
        dict[name]=newOrder;
        vector[newOrder]=dict[name]
    }
    else
    {
        for(var i=oldOrder-1; i>=newOrder; i--)
        {  dict[vector[i]]++;
           vector[i+1]=vector[i];
        }
        dict[name]=newOrder;
        vector[newOrder]=dict[name]
    }
}
```

explanation:

```
add = function(dict, vector, k)
{
    var size=len(vector);
    vector[size]=k;
    dict[k]=size;
}
// vector: 0a 1b 2c 3d 4e
// map: a0 b1 c2 d3 e4

swap(dict, vector, name, newOrder)
{   
    // newOrder = 4

    var oldOrder = dict[name]
    // oldOrder = 1

    if(oldOrder < newOrder)
    {   
        // goes here
        for(var i=oldOrder+1; i<=newOrder; i++)
        {  
           // map: a0 b1 c2 d3 e4
           dict[vector[i]]--;
           // map: a0 b1 c1 d3 e4 //after one iteration

           // vector: 0a 1b 2c 3d 4e
           vector[i-1]=vector[i];
           // vector: 0a 1c 2c 3d 4e //after one iteration

        }
        // map: a0 b1 c1 d2 e3             
     // vector: 0a 1c 2d 3e 4e

        dict[name]=newOrder;
        vector[newOrder]=dict[name]

        // map: a0 b4 c1 d2 e3             
     // vector: 0a 1c 2d 3e 4b
    }
    else
    {
        for(var i=oldOrder-1; i>=newOrder; i--)
        {  dict[vector[i]]++;
           vector[i+1]=vector[i];
        }
        dict[name]=newOrder;
        vector[newOrder]=dict[name]
    }
}
```